# Add sugsetions to an alias

Tags: alias

When you press tab 2 times you get suggestions for possible commands.  For example `lsTabTab` will print all available commands.

Is it possible to add such suggestions to an alias that is user created? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a lot of aliases defined in my `~/.bash_aliases` file and when I type first letter (or two, three...) followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, all the aliases starting with that letter are including in the suggestions.

Also, this works:

```
radu@Radu: ~ $ alias blabla='cd'
radu@Radu: ~ $ blaTabTab some_dir
radu@Radu: ~/some_dir $
```

So, you don't have nothing to do, just try it!